# How to color a cell in python if it contains a specific character?

Tags: python, pandas, styling, conditional-formatting

I am working on a dataframe (from an excel-file) and i would like to format the cells.

The DF has following content (as example):

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 234 --> 500 | 200 --> 500 | 0 |
| 234 --> 500 | 400 | 6 |
| 66 | 34 | 1 |

I would like to color the cells that contain "-->" red. Any suggestions? I know Pandas has a styling function, but i cant find anything that helps me with my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify [color_negative_red](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Building-styles) function for test if exist subtring by `in`:

```
def make_your_style(val):
    """
    Takes a scalar and returns a string with
    the css property `'background-color: red'` for string with -->
    """
    color = 'red' if '-->' in str(val) else ''
    return f'background-color: {color}'

df.style.applymap(make_your_style)
```

[image: img]

For write to excel use:

```
df.style.applymap(make_your_style).to_excel(file, engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are concerned with formatting your Pandas DataFrame, the usual procedure is defining one (or multiple) style functions where you define the CSS properties and then `DF.style.applymap(style_function)` these to your DataFrame.
The conditional formatting can take place either in the style function (as in this example) or by filtering your DataFrame and applying the style_function on the resulting subset!

```
# Function that specifies CSS

def color_fill(val):
    if "-->" in val:
        styling = 'background-color: red; color:black'
    return styling 

df = df.style.applymap(color_fill)
```